# Replacing ontological codes in data file with meanings

Tags: r, ontology, ncbi, icd

I'm pretty novice in using **R**. I'm facing a problem that I used ontological codes in collecting my data (ICD-10, NCBITaxon and CHEBI).

My data is in a long format:

```
   ID    Disease  Organism        Antibiotic 
1  654   N18.0    NCBITaxon:1280  CHEBI:8232 
2 1122   C92.0    NCBITaxon:28037 CHEBI:43968
```

How can I replace the coded ontology with the corresponding meanings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, so I don't know if my advises are useful. R is a big community so there is many initiatives to create packages. The two packages where I guid may help you. I think that for a more useful help you should search a bit by yourself and when you have precise enought questions we can answer them. For the moment, the only advises I can give you are the packages above :

```
install.packages('icd')

library('icd')
library(magrittr)
```

For more help look [their](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/icd/vignettes/introduction.html#filter-patients-and-create-comorbidities).

For taxon look at [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taxize/vignettes/taxize_vignette.html) :

```
install.packages( "taxize")
library(taxize)
genbank2uid(id = 1280)
genbank2uid(id = 28037)
```

For Chebi have a look [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/minval/man/downloadChEBI.html).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Here's a partial solution based on what @Rémi Coulau offered. `code_data %>% 
  mutate(Disease_name = icd::explain_code(Disease)) `